# jQuery Cookie Question

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, detect

I've looked around a lot, and can't seem to find anything that's simple enough for me to do...

I've set up a web page that detects which browser is currently running, and if it's something other than Firefox 4.0, it displays a hidden div that gives a warning stating that the page is best viewed in Firefox 4.0 or greater. Within that div is a button that hides the div onclick.

I'm looking for a way to remember that this button has been clicked during a session, so that when a user clicks on my "home" page, they don't get the same message every time.

Current code:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/browsercheck.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // external script "browsercheck.js" checks
        // which browser/version is being used
        // check browser and display message if != Firefox 4.0 or >
        function checkBrowser() {
            var browser = BrowserDetect.browser;
            var version = BrowserDetect.version;
            if (browser == "Firefox") {
                if (version >= 4) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            } else {
                document.getElementById("coverall").style.visibility="visible";
                document.getElementById("browser").innerHTML = browser + " " + version;
            } 
        }
        // remove overlay if user commands
        function removeCoverall() {
            document.getElementById("coverall").style.visibility="hidden";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="coverall" style="visibility:hidden;">
        <p>I see you're using <span id="browser"></span>. Please use Firefox.</p>
        <button type="button" onclick="removeCoverall()">I understand</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You mention jQuery in the title, but you are not using jQuery at all... how is this question related to jQuery then?

Comment: It doesn't appear that you are using jQuery at all. But if you actually are, take a look at the jquery cookies plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery and the [cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie), you can do:

```
 function removeCoverall() {
            $.cookie("user_clicked_ok", "true");
            document.getElementById("coverall").style.visibility="hidden";
        }

$(window).ready(function() {
  if ($.cookie("user_clicked_ok")=="true") {removeCoverall();}
});
```

More details at: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

Comment: so that looks like it should work, but I'm very new to JS/jQuery. I only know the basics, and for some reason cookies are confounding me. Do you mind putting it exactly how it should be implemented? I can't seem to get this to work

Answer (score 0):

In the `removeCoverall` function you could [set a cookie](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/) which indicates that the user closed the div and in `checkBrowser` function verify if the cookie is present before showing the div.

Answer (score 0):

```
You seem to have the right idea, you need cookies! YUM!
```

**JS**

```
function removeCoverall() {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(7*24*60*60*1000));// expires in one week
    document.cookie = 'skipNotify=1;expires='+date.toGMTString()+'; path=/';
    document.getElementById("coverall").style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

Now retrieving the cookie can be difficult in javascript, but you can use PHP!

**PHP**

```
function checkBrowser() {
    <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['skipNotify']))echo'return;';?>
    var browser = BrowserDetect.browser;
    var version = BrowserDetect.version;
    if (browser == "Firefox") {
        if (version >= 4) {
            // do nothing
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("coverall").style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById("browser").innerHTML = browser + " " + version;
    } 
}
```

The above code injects a return statement if the user has the cookie, so the call to the function won't do anything.

As mentioned in the other posts, I highly recommend you use [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) for all your javascript needs. It's very popular, stable and useful! I only gave my answer as it does not use any third party solution.